# Install zeppelin on windows

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I have spark installed and I am trying to run zeppelin but just doesn't run.
[Error while running Zepplin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98dEL.jpg)

I have used this as JAVA_HOME as "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55"

Could someone please help me with the installation steps of Zeppelin on Windows10 ?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the fact that your zeppelin folder is located in your root directory. You can either:

- Run the cmd window as administrator to start Zeppelin.
- Move the Zeppelin folder in the user directory

Answer (score 0):

What would echo %JAVA_HOME% return?

```
C:\Users\user1>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121
```

Seems like you have extra quotes around the path to your Java directory.

Comment: I tried it without the quotes as well but didn't work for me.

Comment: What is the error message without quotes? Do you actually have `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55` directory? Try to remove `@echo off` instructions from cmd files. so you'll see better diagnostics of what exactly is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues here:
 1. Spaces in your ENV-VARIABLE : You are getting the issue because of the space in your path.
 To resolve it add following lines to your zeppelin-env.cmd

```
set JAVA="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55"
set JAVA_HOME="%JAVA%"
```

This should solve your 'not recognized' error.
 
2a. To troubleshoot zeppelin setup refer [my answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52320063/1276846)

2b. To make spark work on both command prompt and zeppelin [refer this gist.](https://gist.github.com/codspire/7b0955b9e67fe73f6118dad9539cbaa2)

Hope this helps!