# Getting error while running spark programs in Apache Zeppelin in Windows 10 or 7

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I am new to Apache Zeppelin. Installed 0.8.0 and using 7000 port to access Zeppelin. Configured few paths as mentioned below.

JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144
HADOOP_HOME: C:\winutils
ZEPPELIN_HOME: C:\zeppelin\zeppelin-0.8.0-bin-all\zeppelin-0.8.0-bin-all

all these variables are included in path variable and respective bin folders

Tried to run spark program and getting the below error. Tried with multiple options to fix it, but unable. Please help.

**Spark Program:**
%spark
println(sc.appName)

**Error:**
DEBUG [2018-07-29 00:06:05,371] ({pool-2-thread-2} RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.java[start]:153) - callbackServer is serving now
 INFO [2018-07-29 00:06:05,380] ({pool-2-thread-2} RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.java[start]:190) - Run interpreter process [C:\zeppelin\zeppelin-0.8.0-bin-all\zeppelin-0.8.0-bin-all\bin\interpreter.cmd, -d, C:\zeppelin\zeppelin-0.8.0-bin-all\zeppelin-0.8.0-bin-all/interpreter/spark, -c, 10.120.44.23, -p, 57136, -r, :, -l, C:\zeppelin\zeppelin-0.8.0-bin-all\zeppelin-0.8.0-bin-all/local-repo/spark, -g, spark]
DEBUG [2018-07-29 00:06:09,625] ({Exec Stream Pumper} RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.java[processLine]:298) - Warning: Local jar C:\Users\vvellabo\57136 does not exist, skipping.
DEBUG [2018-07-29 00:06:09,626] ({Exec Stream Pumper} RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.java[processLine]:298) - Warning: Local jar C:\Users\vvellabo\10.120.44.23 does not exist, skipping.
DEBUG [2018-07-29 00:06:09,627] ({Exec Stream Pumper} RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.java[processLine]:298) - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer
DEBUG [2018-07-29 00:06:09,628] ({Exec Stream Pumper} RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.java[processLine]:298) -  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
DEBUG [2018-07-29 00:06:09,630] ({Exec Stream Pumper} RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.java[processLine]:298) -  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
DEBUG [2018-07-29 00:06:09,632] ({Exec Stream Pumper} RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.java[processLine]:298) -  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
DEBUG [2018-07-29 00:06:09,633] ({Exec Stream Pumper} RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.java[processLine]:298) -  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
DEBUG [2018-07-29 00:06:09,634] ({Exec Stream Pumper} RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.java[processLine]:298) -  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
DEBUG [2018-07-29 00:06:09,635] ({Exec Stream Pumper} RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.java[processLine]:298) -  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:238)
DEBUG [2018-07-29 00:06:09,641] ({Exec Stream Pumper} RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.java[processLine]:298) -  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:851)
DEBUG [2018-07-29 00:06:09,642] ({Exec Stream Pumper} RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.java[processLine]:298) -  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:198)
DEBUG [2018-07-29 00:06:09,644] ({Exec Stream Pumper} RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.java[processLine]:298) -  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:228)
DEBUG [2018-07-29 00:06:09,645] ({Exec Stream Pumper} RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.java[processLine]:298) -  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:137)
DEBUG [2018-07-29 00:06:09,647] ({Exec Stream Pumper} RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.java[processLine]:298) -  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
DEBUG [2018-07-29 00:06:09,656] ({Exec Stream Pumper} RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.java[processLine]:298) - 2018-07-29 00:06:09 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Shutdown hook called
DEBUG [2018-07-29 00:06:09,659] ({Exec Stream Pumper} RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.java[processLine]:298) - 2018-07-29 00:06:09 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Deleting directory C:\Users\vvellabo\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-427c3202-c243-4761-86ce-ea51a27a881c
 INFO [2018-07-29 00:06:09,747] ({Exec Default Executor} RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.java[onProcessFailed]:250) - Interpreter process failed {}
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 101 (Exit value: 101)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.access$200(DefaultExecutor.java:48)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor$1.run(DefaultExecutor.java:200)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
ERROR [2018-07-29 00:07:05,382] ({pool-2-thread-2} Job.java[run]:190) - Job failed
java.lang.RuntimeException: Warning: Local jar C:\Users\vvellabo\57136 does not exist, skipping.
Warning: Local jar C:\Users\vvellabo\10.120.44.23 does not exist, skipping.

Thanks
vvell

Comment: Have you fixed this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue. Kept coming back to this question in case someone solves it.

**[This link will help you!](https://gist.github.com/codspire/7b0955b9e67fe73f6118dad9539cbaa2)**

If you do not wish to go through the steps, simply delete the **SPARK_HOME** environment variable. Zeppelin has it's own library of spark jars.
Next go to

> %Zeppelin_HOME%\conf\

and rename

> zeppelin-env.cmd.template
> to
> zeppelin-env.cmd

and add following lines:

```
set JAVA="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181"
set JAVA_HOME="%JAVA%"
```

Make sure you enter the correct path to your jdk.
Save it and start zepplin with the command `bin\zeppelin.cmd`

Your zeppelin with Spark is ready! Confirm by running any simple code: For example, `sc.version`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Vishal, Thanks for the update. I followed the steps mentioned in URL provided by you. And its working for me now. One problem I saw is **println()** is not working, not sure how to fix it.

Comment: no error is showing, but println() is not displaying any result, but print() is working.

Comment: @Vishal R grateful for any help on this issue 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54312233/zeppeling-throwing-nullpointerexception-while-configuring